# How do i whitelist a redirect URL for my android app

Tags: java, android, api, redirect, whitelist

Im trying to work with spotify's API, with java on Android studio and one of the requirement is that i whitelist a redirect URI that the Spotify Accounts Service will use to callback to my app after authorization. I've only worked with a weather API in an android app ive built with java on android studio and i didn't whitelist a redirect URL for it, so im lost here.

Comment: Hi MOA - what is your question actually? Try to divide your post into two sections: context and the proper question (one that ends with question mark) :)

Answer (score 1):

Your redirect URI should be the package name of your app, with a `://callback` at the end.

`String REDIRECT_URI = "com.yourdomain.yourapp://callback";`

This looks confusing because it is, but it does say URI not URL so it is correct.

Spotify needs to get back to your app after its authorized the user so it needs to know your app name.

For a guide:
https://developer.spotify.com/documentation/android/quick-start/

For whitelisting: https://developer.spotify.com/dashboard/

Comment: Does my app have to be live, like on Google play store. Because this app is just going to be created and run locally on my phone for now.

Comment: it says " Please enter a valid redirect URI " so it is not taking the package name